# Dividing two variables gives me NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript. My current code seems to work for the total value, but I can't get my division code to work to show how much it's costing per person.

It's this line which seems to be the issue:
   document.getElementById("costeach").innerHTML = '£' + price_each;

It returns NaN but no errors in console.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("quantity");
var price = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
var b = document.getElementById("method");
var type = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;

if (type == 'credit') {
var price = price * 1.034;
}

var price_each = (price / a);

document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = '£' + price;
document.getElementById("costeach").innerHTML = '£' + price_each;
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h4>
Booking Form
</h4>
<select id="quantity" name=''>
  <option title='Option 2' value='240'>2 people</option>
  <option title='Option 3' value='330'>3 people</option>
  <option title='Option 4' value='400'>4 people</option>
  <option title='Option 3' value='500'>5 people</option>
  <option title='Option 4' value='600'>6 people</option>
</select>
<br /> Paypal Funding Method
<br />
<select id="method" name=''>
  <option title='Option 1' value='bank'>Bank Transfer</option>
  <option title='Option 2' value='debit'>Debit Card</option>
  <option title='Option 3' value='credit'>Credit card (+3.4%)</option>
</select>
<br />
<textarea placeholder="Guest names"></textarea>
<br />
<h4>
<b>Total Price</b>
<span id="cost">Hello World!</span>
<b>Price Each</b>
<span id="costeach">Hello World!</span>
</h4>
<button>
  Book
</button>
```

Comment: All values gotten from HTML are strings. Strings are not numbers. You must test the values first and then convert them to numbers before you do math.

Comment: FYI: `a.options[a.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `a.value`.

Comment: look up the javascript method parseInt

Comment: @ScottMarcus Strings are automatically converted to numbers when you use arithmetic operators on them.

Comment: @Barmar What number will this produce: "" / "12"? What will this produce "4" + "9"?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Try `"1" / "2"`

Comment: What are you expecting `price / a` to do? `a` isn't a number. I suspect you're using the wrong variable there.

Comment: @Timo I know, but that's not the scenario I posed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Since none of his values are empty strings, the scenario is not relevant. The problem has nothing to do with the string values, it's that he's dividing by something that isn't a string or number at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ah you helped me figure it out. So I shouldn't be using A but should be using a.value;

Comment: @Barmar That's why I didn't post it as an answer, but instead made a comment.

Comment: @Jimmy You already used `a.value` when you set `price`. What are you trying to divide the price by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly stated in other answers, the reason of the bug is that you are trying to divide a number by a DOM element.

If I correctly understand the intention, you are trying to *divide the price by the number of people.* In order to achieve this, you need to specify the *number of people* somewhere. Of course, you could extract this number from the `option`'s text or derive it from its index, but a cleaner approach is to define this data in **`data` attributes**, e.g.

```
<option title='Option 2' value='240' data-num-persons='2'>2 people</option>
<option title='Option 3' value='330' data-num-persons='3'>3 people</option>
<option title='Option 4' value='400' data-num-persons='4'>4 people</option>
```

Then, you could extract the number of people and do the division like this:

```
var number_of_people = a.options[a.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-num-persons');
var price_each = (price / number_of_people);
```

The rest of your code remains the same. 
**[See fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/zz7nnb5u/4/)**

With this approach, you don't need to make the options' texts nor titles machine-readable, the actual *data* (number of persons) would remain independent of the *representation*. E.g. if you would change the texts to "One person", "Two persons" and so on, the code would still work.

Comment: This raises the question of why he needs the price and number of people in separate attributes. Just put `value="120"` so the division isn't needed.

Comment: Correct, but I believe he needs both total price and price-per-person, so it's either division or multiplication or two "pre-calculated" prices... I'd say two prices would the the best option, but didn't want to suggest too much refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

You are diving a string by a DOM element:

```
var a = document.getElementById("quantity");

// ...

var price_each = (price / a);
```

While the string can automatically be converted to a number, the DOM element can't.

Comment: @AlexShesterov I didn't downvote, but probably it was because it doesn't show how to solve the problem. So it could just be a comment.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the insight... I still think it isn't enough motivation for a downvote, since this answer is technically correct — but it's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

See @Timo [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48530775/6126033) for the details.

You need to change:

`var price_each = (price / a);` to `var price_each = (price / (a.selectedIndex + 1));`

But I strongly suggest to don't do this way, it is better if you create a javascript object with people number an there cost, and get values from there.

Answer (score 1):

I have already reviewed your JSFiddle and the problem is that the value that you are using as quantity was a String

```
<select id="quantity" name=''>
  <option title='Option 2' value='240'>2 </option>
  <option title='Option 3' value='330'>3 </option>
  <option title='Option 4' value='400'>4 </option>
  <option title='Option 3' value='500'>5 </option>
  <option title='Option 4' value='600'>6 </option>
</select>
```

After this change in the options, change this in the js:

```
var a = document.getElementById("quantity");
var price = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
var quantity2 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("method");
var type = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;

if (type == 'credit') {
 var price = price * 1.034;
}

var price_each = (price / quantity2);

document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = '£' + price;
document.getElementById("costeach").innerHTML = '£' + price_each;
```